# KnockoutJS: knowing which item is selected in a dropdown

Tags: knockout.js, html-select, observable

Let's say I have an observable array. This is array contains items which populate a `<select>` list. Is there any way for an option to know whether it is the currently selected option, and to dynamically set the value observable based on that?

`item.isSelected(true)`

I know I could probably make some sort of janky ko.computed with a for each loop to compare what's selected with the items in my array then return true as value or something. Just wondering if there's something more elegant/concise.

With a checkbox it's simple:

`data-bind="checked: isSelected"`

Looking for something as tidy.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you want to use `isSelected`, it can be just be a function that compares the selected value to the item it's a member of. You can data-bind the `isSelected` and the View will respond to changes as if it were an observable. Computeds, as well (because it will access the select's value observable).

It would also work to make it a function in the (parent) viewmodel that takes an item as an argument. The example below shows both usages.

```js
function createItem(name) {
  return {
    name: name,
    isSelected: function() {
      return this === vm.selected();
    }
  };
}
var vm = {
  items: ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(['one', 'two', 'three'], createItem)),
  selected: ko.observable(),
  isSelected: function(item) {
    return vm.selected() === item;
  }
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<select data-bind="options:items, optionsText:'name', value:selected"></select>
<ul data-bind="foreach:items">
  <li data-bind="text:name, css:{selected: $parent.isSelected($data)}"></li>
</ul>
<ul data-bind="foreach:items">
  <li data-bind="text:name, css:{selected: isSelected()}"></li>
</ul>
```